# separar objetos

Tags: java, jtable

mi problema es que necesito separar un Object y no se siquiera si se puede hacer.

en el software el usuario debe de ingresar una cantidad que desee de jugadores inscritos en una DB por nombre y apellido, luego llamo esa lista para ponerla en una tabla versus 
Ejemplo:
si son 10 jugadores, deben estar distribuidos en un Jtable con tres columnas ("Jugador 1","V/S","Jugador 2") donde en la primera y ultima fila se inserten 5 nombres de manera aleatoria.

```
while (result.next()){
        //los resultset traidos como nombre y apellido 
        //insertados en un String
        nombre =result.getString("nombre")+" "+result.getString("apellido");

      //Creo un Object para guardar todos los resultados
      //Lo pongo dentro de un DefaultTableModel como fila
      dtm.addRow( new Object[] {nombre});
       }
```

Versus.setModel(qsjt.buscarTablaTorneo(IDTORNEO,A));

con eso la inserto en mi tabla

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Lvz.png [![asi me queda eso][1]][1]

necesito separar eso para poder enfrentar a mis jugadores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle esta en esta linea.

> dtm.addRow( new Object[] {nombre});

Debes separar los valores de la siguiente manera, ya que cada item representa la columna de cada fila.

```
Object jugadores[]={ "Jugador 1",//  columna del primer jugador
                     " ", //segunda columna vacia
                     "Jugador 2" //columna del segundo jugador
                    };      
    dtm.addRow(jugadores); // se ingresa los valores previos
```

Comment: disculpa si no me expresé bien, necesito que el nombre y apellido vallan concatenados para para saber que "juan pérez" se enfrentará a "diego fernandez" ya que en mi DB el nombre y apellido van en columnas separadas es por eso que hago esto: 
nombre =result.getString("nombre")+" "+result.getString("apellido");
y para que el nombre y apellido quede junto en una sola columna lo inserto con esta linea creando un objeto por participante:
  dtm.addRow( new Object[] {nombre});
    El asunto es que no logro dividir todos los participantes seleccionados para ponerlos en dos columnas distintas